# Regex to ignore closed curly brackets and semicolumn

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using codemirror for some user inputted groovy text and before I submit the form to the server I want to add a semicolumn after every closed curly bracket. The way I'm doing it now is:

```
editor.getValue().replace(/}/g,"};")
```

This works fine if there are no `};` already in the text I'm submitting. Is there any way to extend my regex to ignore this specific string combination(`};`) before I replace?

Comment: You'll break `if {...} else {...}` by doing this.

Comment: honestly i'm pretty weak when it comes to groovy syntax, but i was told the user input should have semicolons after each closed curly bracket. I believe it is being parsed in some sort of weird way before being used as actual groovy code

Comment: That's fine, I'm just alerting you to the fact that a regular expression isn't sufficient to insert semi-colons into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
  "editor.getValue().replace(/}(?!;)/g,"};")".
```

and to account for spaces between } and ;

```
  "editor.getValue().replace(/}(?!\s*;)/g,"};")".
```

Answer (score 1):

`/}(?!;)/g` should do it for you.

Comment: No that will replace the charcater after { also.

Comment: Yeah I know, just changed it. Wasn't sure if js had lookaheads and had to do a quick search.

Answer (score 1):

Go with

```
editor.getValue().replace(/}/g, "};")
```

however if you don't want to add `;` if there already is some, go with

```
editor.getValue().replace(/}(?!;)/g, "};")
```